# How to check if a file is empty using awk in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am trying to check if a file is empty using `awk` in a bash script. This condition for a file being empty is the following: If a file only has its first row with field values followed by `------` (and followed by nothing else) then it is considered empty.

Here is the structure of that special file:

file.txt

```
col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
------
```

So far this is what I have:

```
awk '
    {
      if (NR > 2)
        print "NOT EMPTY"
      else
        print "EMPTY"
    }
' file.txt
```

The output I want is:

```
EMPTY
```

The empty I am getting is:

```
EMPTY
EMPTY
```

How do I get only `EMPTY` as one output? I know it might be very simple but I couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Let me know if further explanation is needed.

EDIT: Also, if extra blank lines are added to file.txt, then it will print `EMPTY` for as many extra line there is. Is there a more general approach to this?

Comment: `{ -> END{` will help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put your awk logic in `END` block otherwise it is executed for each line of input:

```
awk '
    END {
      if (NR > 2)
        print "NOT EMPTY"
      else
        print "EMPTY"
    }
' file.txt
```

Comment: I want to store it in a var but it won't allow me. I tried `var=awk'...' file.txt` but I keep getting an error, do you know why?

Comment: @Alias `var=$(awk '...' file.txt)`. You need to tell the shell to run the command and capture the output.

Answer (score 6):

```
awk 'END{print(NR>2)?"NOT EMPTY":"EMPTY"}'
```

Comment: or even `awk 'END{print (NR>2?"NOT ":"") "EMPTY"}'`